# Delete trailing whitespace only in code chunks in markdown

Tags: whitespace, markdown

I dislike trailing whitespace, so I have emacs remove trailing whitespace at every file-save.

Unfortunately, in markdown trailing whitespaces are part of the syntax, as markdown uses two trailing whitespaces code for line breaks ([docs](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#block)).

So, I exclude markdown-mode buffers from the trailing-white-space-deleting:

```
(defun my-delete-trailing-whitespace ()
  "In markdown mode do nothing.  Outside markdown, delete trailing whitespace."
  (interactive)
  (when (not (derived-mode-p 'markdown-mode)) (delete-trailing-whitespace)))
```

Unfortunately, now the trailing whitespace is not deleted in code chunks in (R)markdown files.

So, my question is: How can I delete trailing white space in also in markdown files, but **only within the code chunks**?

I work with Rmarkdown quite a bit and use `poly-markdown+r-mode` to edit those, in case that is relevant.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here is the full part of my config for this matter:

```
(defun my-delete-trailing-whitespace ()
  "In markdown mode do nothing.  Outside markdown, delete trailing whitespace."
  (interactive)
  (when (not (derived-mode-p 'markdown-mode)) (delete-trailing-whitespace)))

;; from http://whattheemacsd.com//buffer-defuns.el-01.html
(defun cleanup-buffer-safe ()
  "Perform a bunch of safe operations on the whitespace content of a buffer.
Does not indent buffer, because it is used for a before-save-hook, and that
might be bad."
  (interactive)
  (my-delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))

;; Various superfluous white-space. Just say no.
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'cleanup-buffer-safe)
```